# Prove that $1+a+a^2+...+a^n$ = $\frac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a}$ for all $a\ne 1$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

I've started by saying $a_n$=$1+a+a^2+...+a^n$=$\frac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a}$

Now I think I need to do: $lim_{n\to \infty}$$\frac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a}$

Should let $a=2$ and then solve the limit, then write a proof for it using $\epsilon$?

I've also considered that $1+a+a^2+...+a^n$=$1+a^n$. But I'm not sure what to do with this information.

I'd like to understand how to start this problem properly.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You can multiply out
$$(1+a+a^2+…+a^n)(1-a)=…$$

Comment: OH! That's way easier than I was trying to make it. So:

Comment: That is nice, i hope you can solve your problem now!

Comment: And a hint again: $$\lim_{n\to \infty}a^n=0$$ if $$|a|<1$$

Answer (score 0):

Or,
a standard proof by induction.

$1+a+a^2+...+a^n
=\dfrac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a}
$
is true for
$n=0$ and $n=1$.

If true for $n$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
1+a+a^2+...+a^n+a^{n+1}
&=(1+a+a^2+...+a^n)+a^{n+1}\\
&=\dfrac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a}+a^{n+1}\\
&=\dfrac{1-a^{n+1}+a^{n+1}(1-a)}{1-a}\\
&=\dfrac{1-a^{n+1}+a^{n+1}-a^{n+2}}{1-a}\\
&=\dfrac{1-a^{n+2}}{1-a}\\
\end{array}
$

which completes the proof.